# My rails helper is rendering '<' as '&lt;'! How to make it render correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, helper

I'm working on a simple plugin here, and this far it is working. 
Except my helper. 
Its a very simple helper, it just needs to echo a *`<span></span>`* for later javascript parsing.

The problem is, its not rendering the html correcty, its replacing special chars by the html equivalent code.

My plugin initializer:

```
ActionView::Helpers.send :include, Test
```

My plugin helper:

```
module Test    
  def only_for_testing
    render(:text => "<span></span>")
  end
end
```

When I call the only_for_testing helper inside the view, instead of rendering the `"<span></span>"` it renders "`&lt;span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;`"

I tryed remove the render, return only the string, same effect.
I really dont want to create a partial for this, because its a very very simple html, and its not for layout, its just for parsing.

Any idea what i may have done wrong here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Rails 3 escapes HTML by default in the view.  You need to use the raw() helper or "HTML string here".html_safe

Answer (score 6):

```
module Test    
  def only_for_testing
    render(:html=> "<span></span>")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

in rails 3.2, my helper did not recognize the ":html" symbol, 
but I believe it's been replaced with ":inline" as this is what worked for me

```
module IndexHelper
    def logo
        render(:inline=> "<div class='css_name'></div>")
    end
end
```